# Integral when denominator is 0

Tags: integration

I am trying to integrate this function as tagged :
[image]

In the picture there is this integral which i know hot to integrate however when i compute this definite integral online it gives me the value as shown in the figure. However clearly im confused cause one of my limits is -0.6 which implies that in on of the terms the denominator will become 0 and hence undefined. So I am confused how does computing manually give me undefined values but online and it gives me a defined value?

Comment: What integral did you get manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically considering the problem of $$I=\int_{-a}^0\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$$ This does not make problem at the lower bound; consider the Taylor expansion of the integrand around $x=-a$. You should get
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a}  \sqrt{a+x}}+\frac{\sqrt{a+x}}{4 \sqrt{2}
   a^{3/2}}+O\left((x+a)^{3/2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Just as the sum of an infinite number of summands can be finite:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} = 2$$

the area under a function that goes to infinity can sometimes be approximated by the sum of an infinite number of ever smaller summands.

As far as this particular case, when you take the integral, the result is no longer undefined.

Answer (score 0):

This integral is an improper integral. It is eas the limit of the intergarl from $a$ to $0$ as $ a \to -0.6$. This limit is finite even though the integrand is not defined at $-0.6$.